# Phone validation with DataAnnotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, data-annotations

I would like to validate my phone number and for each non valid case I would like to have another error message:

So, my validation rules:

1. Only 9 digits -> error message = "error message 1"
2. Number couldn't be with the same number e.g 222222222 > error
   message = "error message 2"
3. Can't be string like '123456789' > error message = "error message 3"
4. Can't start with 0 > error message ="error message 4"

MyPhoneAttribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class MyPhoneAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    private const string myRegex = @"^([0-9]{9}){0,1}$";

    public MyPhoneAttribute () : base(myRegex )
    {
        ErrorMessage = "default error message";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
            return true;

        if (value.ToString() == "123456789")
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), @"^([0-9])\1*$"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), @"^([0-9])\1*$");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: I don't know how to create validation rules with diffrent error mesages.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/validating-data-using-data-annotation-attributes-in-asp.net-mvc.htm

Comment: @Wenson I would like to have my own attribute

Comment: No problem using regex is easiest way.

Comment: var pattern = /^\d{9}$/ for nine digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the perfect solution and I'll improve it later but for now you can try something like (note, here I used `ValidationAttribute` but not `RegularExpressionAttribute` as a base class):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class MyPhoneAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string nineDigitsPattern = @"^([0-9]{9}){0,1}$";
    private const string sameNumberPattern = @"(\w)\1{9,}"; // here 9 the same numbers

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var validationNumber = (string)value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationNumber))
            return true;

        // case 4
        if (validationNumber.StartsWith("0"))
        {
            ErrorMessage = "error message 4";
            return false;
        }

        // case 3       
        if (validationNumber.Equals("123456789"))
        {
            ErrorMessage = "error message 3";
            return false;
        }

        // case 2
        if (Regex.IsMatch(validationNumber, sameNumberPattern)) {
            ErrorMessage = "error message 2";
            return false;
        }

        // case 1
        if (Regex.IsMatch(validationNumber, nineDigitsPattern))
        {
            ErrorMessage = "error message 1";
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's work fine, but how can I implent it to client side validation ?

Comment: Sorry, I promised improve it but I really did not have time. You should use JavaScript(jquery.validate.js) but it have to be a new question. If it was helpful, please accept the answer. Thanks